# Is it possible to use implicit evidence to force static type compatibility between abstract types?

Tags: scala

Assume the following trait:

```
trait A {
  type B
  def +(a:A):A
}
```

I use an abstract type because I don't want to drag around the B in the type signature everytime I need an A. 
Is it still possible to add any implicit evidence (using =:=,<:<, etc.) to the + method so that the compiler can still enforce acceptance of a:A's with identical B's?

My first instinct is to say no, but scala has pleasantly surprised me before. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need for implicit evidence ... you can use an explicit refinement,

```
trait A {
  self =>
  type Self = A { type B = self.B }
  type B
  def +(a : Self) : Self
}
```

(note the use of a self type annotation to provide an alias for the outer 'this' allowing the defined and defining B's to be distinguished in the definition of type Self).

REPL transcript,

```
scala> trait A { self => type Self = A { type B = self.B } ; type B ; def +(a : Self) : Self }
defined trait A

scala> val ai = new A { type B = Int ; def +(a : Self) : Self = this }
ai: java.lang.Object with A{type B = Int} = $anon$1@67f797

scala> val ad = new A { type B = Double ; def +(a : Self) : Self = this }
ad: java.lang.Object with A{type B = Double} = $anon$1@7cb66a

scala> ai + ai
res0: ai.Self = $anon$1@67f797

scala> ad + ad 
res1: ad.Self = $anon$1@7cb66a

scala> ai + ad
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : ab.type (with underlying type java.lang.Object with A{type B = Double})
 required: ai.Self
       ai + ab
```

Comment: I can't believe that the compiler doesn't complain about a cycle!

Comment: Does structural refinement also depend on reflections at run time?

Comment: Runtime reflection is only involved when a refinement provides a new non-type definition which isn't present in it's nominal supertype (see SLS 3.2.7). That's not happening here so, no, no runtime reflection involved. You can verify that by using javap.

Comment: Really neat trick. Perhaps would be clearer if Self was renamed WithSameB or something.