# Defining an ordering on traits with abstract types which compiles only for compatible types?

Tags: scala

Assume the following trait:

```
trait A {
  type B       
}
```

Is there any way of making this into an ordered type, where only A's with the same B's can be compared, and this is enforced in compile time?

Comment: Perhaps might help you: [Is it possible to use implicit evidence to force static type compatibility between abstract types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909890/is-it-possible-to-use-implicit-evidence-to-force-static-type-compatibility-betwee/5910291#5910291)

Comment: @user44242 Ok, Miles elaborated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, via an implicit (with a type alias to make things a little more DRY),

```
type AA[T] = A { type B = T }

implicit def aIsOrdered[T](a : AA[T]) = new Ordered[AA[T]] {
  def compare(that : AA[T]) = 0
}
```

Sample REPL session,

```
scala> val ai1 = new A { type B = Int }
ai1: java.lang.Object with A{type B = Int} = $anon$1@1ec264c

scala> val ai2 = new A { type B = Int }
ai2: java.lang.Object with A{type B = Int} = $anon$1@1a8fb1b

scala> val ad = new A { type B = Double }
ad: java.lang.Object with A{type B = Double} = $anon$1@891a0

scala> ai1 < ai2
res2: Boolean = false

scala> ai1 < ad
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : ad.type (with underlying type java.lang.Object with A{type B = Double})
 required: AA[Int]
       ai1 < ad
             ^
```

**Edit ...**

Thanks to the implicit definitions in scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits this defintion is sufficient to provide us with corresponding Ordering type class instances. This allows us to use A with types which require Orderings, eg. a scala.collection.SortedSet,

```
scala> implicitly[Ordering[AA[Int]]]
res0: Ordering[AA[Int]] = scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits$$anon$4@39cc63

scala> import scala.collection.SortedSet
import scala.collection.SortedSet

scala> val s = SortedSet(ai1, ai2)
s: scala.collection.SortedSet[java.lang.Object with A{type B = Int}] = TreeSet($anon$1@1a8fb1b)
```

Comment: Uh, so you can use a type alias to extract a type memeber back into a type parameter? I was looking for this some time ago.

Comment: Two questions: How would you generate an ordering that would work for SortedSet, and would this work if the method accepts A's only, and the B is lost?

Comment: If you method accept plain A's without the refinement then the behaviour is equivalent to what you would expect with a wildcarded type parameter (ie. a hidden abstract type member is equivalent to a wildcarded type parameter).

Comment: So basically, once I have to explicitly type a variable, unless I type it with the refinement, I lose the refinement? Basically, this means that anytime I try to put these things in a collection, I lose the ordering defined.

Comment: Yes, you do have to mention the refinement if you want the compiler to keep the information about B (compare List[Int] vs. List[_]). But that doesn't mean that you have to lose the Ordering when you put things in collections ... see my SortedSet example above. OTOH, if you're trying to put A values with different B types into a single SortedSet, then the compiler is quite right to complain because there is no single applicable Ordering.

Answer (score 0):

How about making `B` a parameter of `A`?

```
trait A[B] {
    compare(x: A[B]): Int
}
```

Comment: The use of abstract types is precisely to remove the need to carry the B around anywhere a dependency on type A is defined